# upgrade postgresql version ( MAMP OS X Yosemite)

Tags: postgresql, mamp, osx-yosemite

I need to upgrade postgresql from 9.3 to 9.5 .
I upgraded it from terminal ( postgres -V returns 9.5.3)
However MAMP still uses old postgresql version (9.3)
What path/config  should be changed for MAMP to use later version?
Thanks